# Improving on pandas tolist() performance

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following operation which takes about `1s` to perform on a pandas dataframe with 200 columns:

```
for col in mycols:
    values = [str(_item) if col_raw_type == 'object' else '{:f}'.format(_item) 
     for _item in df[col_name].dropna().tolist() 
     if (_item is not None) and str(_item)]
```

Is there a more optimal way to do this? It seems perhaps the `tolist` operation is a bit slow?

What I'm trying to do here is convert something like:

```
field         field2
'2014-01-01'  1.0000000
'2015-01-01'  nan
```

Into something like this:

```
values_of_field_1 = ['2014-01-01', '2015-01-01']
values_of_field_2 = [1.00000,]
```

So I can then infer the type of the columns. For example, the end product I'd want would be to get:

```
type_of_field_1 = DATE # %Y-%m-%d
type_of_field_2 = INTEGER #
```

Comment: If there a certain reason you want to use a list iterable instead of the NumPy array collection that's already used?

Comment: `tolist` will be the fastest way of converting some pandas data structure to a list. Whether or not that is the best way to achieve what you are trying to do, I don't know. Maybe you can explain what you are trying to do...

Comment: @blacksite nope, I have no preference. I'm just learning pandas so whatever is the best way to use it.

Comment: @blacksite I"m trying to get all the values and determine their type. It doesn't necessarily need to be in a python list, but I do need to iterate over the items and convert them all to a string. So, for example, I can see that "2014-01-01" is probably a date.

Comment: Look into [`pd.Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html)... Specifically the `errors` option.

Comment: @blacksite could you please show an example of how that might be done?

Comment: Sure, coming right up...

Comment: Please answer @juanpa.arrivillaga's question, it is key to solving the X in your XY problem

Comment: @DavidL what do you mean by "type"? Again, **please be specific about what you are trying to achieve**. Providing a good problem specification is the best way to get help around here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga question has been updated with an example.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to cast entire `Series` columns within a `DataFrame` to a certain type. Taking this `DataFrame` as an example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
```

Create a DataFrame with columns with mixed types:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, np.nan, 2, 'a', None, 'b'], 'b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'c': [np.nan, np.nan, 2, 2, 'a', 'a']})
>>> df
      a  b    c
0     1  1  NaN
1   NaN  2  NaN
2     2  3    2
3     a  4    2
4  None  5    a
5     b  6    a
>>> df.dtypes
a    object
b     int64
c    object
dtype: object
>>> for col in df.select_dtypes('object'):
...     print(col)
...     print('\n'.join('{}: {}'.format(v, type(v)) for v in df[col]))
... 
a
1: <class 'int'>
nan: <class 'float'>
2: <class 'int'>
a: <class 'str'>
None: <class 'NoneType'>
b: <class 'str'>
c
nan: <class 'float'>
nan: <class 'float'>
2: <class 'int'>
2: <class 'int'>
a: <class 'str'>
a: <class 'str'>
```

Use `pd.Series.astype` to cast `object` dtypes to `str`:

```
>>> for col in df.select_dtypes('object'):
...     df[col] = df[col].astype(str)
...     print(col)
...     print('\n'.join('{}: {}'.format(v, type(v)) for v in df[col]))
... 
a
1: <class 'str'>
nan: <class 'str'>
2: <class 'str'>
a: <class 'str'>
None: <class 'str'>
b: <class 'str'>
c
nan: <class 'str'>
nan: <class 'str'>
2: <class 'str'>
2: <class 'str'>
a: <class 'str'>
a: <class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think tolist() is making your code slow, then you can remove tolist(). There is no need to use tolist() at all. Below code would give you the same output.

```
for col in mycols:
    values = [str(_item) if col_raw_type == 'object' else '{:f}'.format(_item) 
     for _item in df[col_name].dropna()
     if (_item is not None) and str(_item)]
```